# Spring session tries serialize service with session scope

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, session, spring-boot, aop

I have a service

```
@Service
@Scope(value = SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyService {
    public void method() throws MyException {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

And a Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String do() {
        myService.method();
        return null;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<MyException> exceptionHandler(MyException e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<MyException>(e, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }
}
```

And configuration file:

```
@EnableRedisHttpSession
public class AppConfig {
}
```

When I request do method of controller, service throws `MyException`, `ExceptionHandler` catch it. But after `exceptionHandler` return, I have an Exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: Cannot serialize; nested exception is org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [my.example.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$442fa3ef_5]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:92) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.rawHashValue(AbstractOperations.java:171) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.putAll(DefaultHashOperations.java:129) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultBoundHashOperations.putAll(DefaultBoundHashOperations.java:86) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.saveDelta(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:778) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository$RedisSession.access$000(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:670) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:388) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.data.redis.RedisOperationsSessionRepository.save(RedisOperationsSessionRepository.java:245) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.commitSession(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:245) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter$SessionRepositoryRequestWrapper.access$100(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:217) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:170) ~[spring-session-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ...
Caused by: org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException: Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [my.example.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$442fa3ef_5]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:68) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:35) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.serialize(JdkSerializationRedisSerializer.java:90) ~[spring-data-redis-1.8.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a Serializable payload but received an object of type [my.example.MyService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$442fa3ef_5]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.DefaultSerializer.serialize(DefaultSerializer.java:43) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializingConverter.convert(SerializingConverter.java:63) ~[spring-core-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
```

While debugging, I've got that session tries to serialize `Myservice` object to key `"sessionAttr:scopedTarget.myService"`

I do not whant to make MyService class Serializeble. Is there any another solutions?

Answer (score 3):

Your bean should be serializable like below:

```
@Service
@Scope(value = SCOPE_SESSION, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class MyService implements Serializable {
    public void method() throws MyException {
        throw new MyException();
    }
}
```

The reason Is that using redis your bean must be ready to be serialized

1. the bean have travel in the network to redis
2. the bean have serialized in redis data store

Probably you should think of don't use redis as session store, infact i belive that you need that a fresh instance of bean for every session and for this reaso a centralized session datastore may be not effective, a classical approach may be better for this propouse.

I hope that this reflection may be usefull for you to understand why I consider that you should be think to an anoder solutions.

Comment: Also, if your bean is named "Service", that probably means you shouldn't use @Scope("session") in the first place. Session-scoped beans are for persisting session state. "Service"-like objects should be stateless, so they can safely be used as singletons (Spring's default scope).
As a general rule, use default scope (i.e. singleton) for Services; if they need session state, put that state in a seperate session-scoped bean (which as a dumb serializable POJO) and inject that into your Service.